# Looping a Python split function

Tags: python

I'm trying to strip subdomains off of a large list of domains in a text file. The script works but only for the last domain in the list. I know the problem is in the loop but can't pinpoint the extact issue. Thanks for any assistance:)

```
with open ("domainlist.txt", "r") as datafile:
s = datafile.read()
for x in s:
    t = '.'.join(s.split('.')[-2:])

print t
```

this will take "example.test.com" and "return test.com". The only problem is it won't perform this for every domain in the list - only the last one.

Comment: You don't use `x` in your loop :)

Comment: How does your input file look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is to build up a new list, by modifying the elements of an old one, fortunately, Python has [the list comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw) - perfect for this job.

```
with open("domainlist.txt", "r") as datafile:
    modified = ['.'.join(x.split('.')[-2:]) for x in datafile]
```

This behaves exactly like creating a list and adding items to it in a for loop, except faster and nicer to read. I recommend watching the video linked above for more information on how to use them.

Note that `file.read()` reads the entire thing in as one big string, what you wanted was probably to loop over the lines of the file, which is done just by looping over the file itself. Your current loop loops of the individual *characters* of the file, rather than lines.

Answer (score 2):

You are overwriting t in each loop iteration, so naturally only the value from the last iteration stays in t. INstead put the string inside a list with list.append.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out. Better readability.

```
with open ("domainlist.txt", "r") as datafile:
s = datafile.readlines()

t = []

for x in s:
    t.append('.'.join(x.split('.')[-2:]))

print t
```